# how to download and share the pdf file using swift

Tags: ios, swift, url

In the application I am building I have to generate a pdf file and then share via email, WhatsApp, etc.

Currently I have followed the below code for the generation of pdf.

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var masterContainerView: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var pdfButton: UIButton!

        @IBAction func generatePDFtapped(_ sender: Any) {
            pdfButton.isHidden = true
            generatePDF()
            pdfButton.isHidden = false
        }

        func generatePDF() {
            let pdfWrittenPath = masterContainerView.exportAsPdfFromView()
            print("PDF written at \(pdfWrittenPath)")
        }
    }
```

The above code is the view controller and the class file is this:

```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit

    //to call this, use the <viewoutletname>.exportAsPdfFromView()

    extension UIView {
        // Export pdf from Save pdf in directory and return pdf file path


        func exportAsPdfFromView() -> String {
            let pdfPageFrame = self.bounds
            let pdfData = NSMutableData()
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageFrame, nil)
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageFrame, nil)
            guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return "" }
            self.layer.render(in: pdfContext)
            UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
            return self.saveViewPdf(data: pdfData)

        }

        // Save pdf file in document directory
        func saveViewPdf(data: NSMutableData) -> String {
            let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            let docDirectoryPath = paths[0]
            let pdfPath = docDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent("viewPdf.pdf")
            if data.write(to: pdfPath, atomically: true) {
                return pdfPath.path
                print("PDF written at path \(pdfPath.path)")
            } else {
                return ""
            }
        }
    }
```

I found a useful example on the Internet which explains exactly what I have to do. But my problem is in that `EXAMPLE` the developer is accessing a public `URL` instead it should load the PDF File saved (which is stored). Please help me to modify the code.

https://github.com/mansi-cherry/iOSHowTo-s/blob/master/documentInteractionDemo/documentInteractionDemo/ViewController.swift

> ---

[expected output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izPN9.png)
here is the expected output but instead of fetching an image file  a pdf should be fetched

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to load the file you have previously saved?

Do the same thing to access the file name and path and then read the contents.

```
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let docDirectoryPath = paths.first
let pdfPath = docDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent("viewPdf.pdf")

let data = Data(contentsOf: pdfPath)
```

Full example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let dataString = "Helloooooo world"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        saveFile()
        readFile()
    }

    func saveFile() {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let docDirectoryPath = paths.first
        let pdfPath = docDirectoryPath?.appendingPathComponent("test.txt")

        let data = dataString.data(using: .utf8)
        try? data?.write(to: pdfPath!)
    }

    func readFile() {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let docDirectoryPath = paths.first
        let pdfPath = docDirectoryPath?.appendingPathComponent("test.txt")

        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: pdfPath!)
        let str = String(bytes: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        print("[DEBUG] result is \(str)")
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> [DEBUG] result is Optional("Helloooooo world")

Comment: hi thanks for the workaround currently my file is getting saved in this link /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/48273470-2CB4-4ECD-B7CD-39908941DFD2/data/Containers/Data/Application/49FEFAB7-E571-4E86-8F7E-4EF08575279A/Documents/viewPdf.pdf @Scriptable

Comment: it's not a workaround, this demonstrates how to read the file data. the full path doesn't matter, you get the full path to the documents directory anyway from the `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)` call.

Comment: iam not able to open pdf which is downloaded.So as per the requirement I want to preview it and then share it through other applications or gmail like that.Could you please help how can I do this @Scriptable

Comment: see this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860593/share-pdf-file-with-uiactivityviewcontroller